# Gunicorn giving worker timeout issue

Tags: flask, gunicorn, gevent

I am facing worker timeout issue. when this happens api gets timeout issue.
Please look into log and settings.

Here is log:

> [2016-11-26 09:45:02 +0000] [19064] [INFO] Autorestarting worker after current request.
>     [2016-11-26 09:45:02 +0000] [19064] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19064)
>     [2016-11-26 09:46:02 +0000] [19008] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:19064)
>     [2016-11-28 04:12:06 +0000] [19008] [INFO] Handling signal: winch

gunicorn config:

```
workers = threads = numCPUs() * 2 + 1
backlog = 2048
max_requests = 1200
timeout = 60
preload_app = True
worker_class = "gevent"
debug = True
daemon = False
pidfile = "/tmp/gunicorn.pid"
logfile = "/tmp/gunicorn.log"
loglevel = 'info'
accesslog = '/tmp/gunicorn-access.log'
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes. After particular timeout worker trying to restart.
So i changed **preload_app = False**. After that, i haven't face above issue.